# System of inequalities with assumptions

Tags: inequalities

I have the following problem:

I have a Variable `a` for which I know that `-5<a<-2` is valid.

Furthermore, I have the following two equations:

```
EV1 = -0.5*b + 0.5*Sqrt[b^2 - 4*c]
EV2 = -0.5*b - 0.5*Sqrt[b^2 - 4*c]
```

with

```
b = -a + 3.4 + L2
c = (a + 0.2)*(3.2 + L2) - 0.25*(-9.5 - L1)^2
```

Based on those equations, I want to compute an `L1>2` and an `L2` such that `EV1<-2` and `EV2<-2` for all `a` in the defined interval `-5<a<-2`.

I have already tried

```
$Assumptions = -5 < a < -2
(*1*)
Simplify[Reduce[EV1 < -2 && EV2 < 2 && L1 >= 2, {L1, L2}]]
(*2*)
Simplify[FindInstance[EV1 < 1.7 && EV2 < 1.7 && L1 >= 2, {L1, L2}]]
```

Unfortunately, both didn't work.

Does anybody know a possible way to compute an instance for `L1` and `L2` fulfilling the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

If you use rational numbers in your variables and equations, Reduce works and shows you, that you conditions can't get fullfilled.

```
      b = Rationalize[-a + 3.4 + L2, 0]
      c = Rationalize[(a + 0.2)*(3.2 + L2) - 0.25*(-9.5 - L1)^2, 0]

      EV1[L1_, L2_] = -1/2*b + 1/2*Sqrt[b^2 - 4*c] // Simplify
      EV2[L1_, L2_] = -1/2*b - 1/2*Sqrt[b^2 - 4*c] // Simplify

      (red = 
      Reduce[EV1[L1, L2] < -2 && EV2[L1, L2] < -2 && 
      L1 >= 2 && -5 < a < -2, {L1, L2}])

      (*  False  *)
```